# Is it possible to use gem mysql2 with rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I can't find anything related to how to use mysql2 with rails 2.3. Is it possible to use these two together? I want to use mysql2 since I think it would help the performance my rails 2.3 app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mysql2 gem works fine with my rails 2.3.5 but you need to use 0.2.* version of the gem

```
gem install mysql2 -v=0.2.6
```

Comment: Or add to your Gemfile: `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'`

Answer (score 2):

I got the `Task not supported by 'mysql2'` error after upgrading a rails app from 2.3.5 to 2.3.8. The error occurs when rake tasks such as `db:test:purge` are invoked.

To fix this, feel free to download my version from https://github.com/zubin/rails/tree/v.2.3.8.mysql2 into `vendor/rails`.